# ¿Cómo cambio el color de las variables de mi gráfico y cómo agrego una leyenda?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Buen día.

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```
estaciones[[1]]-> est1
pdf("0011105020-0068/0011105020 - Abril.pdf")

ggplot(est1, aes(x = hora, y = p05)) +
  ggtitle("0011105020 - Abril") +
  xlab("Hora") +
  ylab("Temperatura") +
  geom_line()+
geom_line(data = est1, aes(x = hora, y = p5)) +
geom_line(data =est1, aes(x = hora, y = p95))
dev.off()
```

Que me genera el siguiente gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo cambiar el color de cada línea (cada una corresponde a un percentil diferente (0.05, 0.5, 0.95) y, además, que a a un costado salga una mini leyenda indicando precisamente cuál línea/color corresponde a cada percentil.

He intentado de varias maneras pero no logró dar con la forma de que la leyenda o el color salga correctamente.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Muchas gracias!

Adjunto un archivo de datos para hacer más práctica la cuestión:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/135Bp3Nr28cLJe79HqjMla8qhkjPTzYcJ?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que es más simple pasar los datos formato largo usando `gather()` y luego definir un color y grupo en ggplot. De ese modo sale automáticamente el color y la leyenda de colores. Lo más complicadillo es el `gather()`. Ahí le paso 5 argumentos: el nombre que tendrán las claves (nombres de variables, en este caso "percentil"), el nombre de la columna en la que se registran los valores de esas variables (en este caso valor) y, por último, los nombres de variables que quiero que se alarguen.

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
est1 <- read_csv("0011105020 - Abril.csv")

est1 %>% 
  gather(percentil, valor, p05, p5, p95) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hora, y = valor, color = percentil, group = percentil)) +
  ggtitle("0011105020 - Abril") +
  xlab("Hora") +
  ylab("Temperatura") +
  geom_line()
```

Queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias a ambos por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Resuelvo la duda de una forma muy tosca, seguro que hay otra más simple y corta. Se crean 3 estructuras con las columnas: `px` (valor del percentil), `hora` y `Type` (tipo de percentil) , la idea es crear una variable que sirva para distinguir un valor de otro y así, obtener un color por cada columna:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

estaciones<- read_csv("Abril.csv")

df1 <- estaciones %>%  
  select(p05,hora)%>%
  mutate(Type = 'p05')

df2 <- estaciones %>%  
  select(p5,hora)%>%
  mutate(Type = 'p5')

df3 <- estaciones %>%  
  select(p95,hora)%>%
  mutate(Type = 'p95')

ggplot(df1, aes(x = hora, y = p05, color = Type)) +
  ggtitle("0011105020 - Abril") +
  xlab("Hora") +
  ylab("Temperatura") +
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = hora, y = p5, color = Type)) +
  geom_line(data =df3, aes(x = hora, y = p95,color = Type))
```

O simplemente, añadir el tipo manualmente y cambiar el título de la leyenda como guste.

```
  ggplot(estaciones, aes(x = hora, y = p05, color = "p05")) +
  ggtitle("0011105020 - Abril") +
  xlab("Hora") +
  ylab("Temperatura") +
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data = estaciones, aes(x = hora, y = p5, color = "p5")) +
  geom_line(data = estaciones, aes(x = hora, y = p95,color = "p95")) +
  labs(color='Tipo de percentil')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por la ayuda! de ambos aprendí algo nuevo!